# Is there a way to find out the partition index/Id/number of a particular Kafka msg which is being published to a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, jbpm

We are trying to publish the messages in a clustered environment, with n no of partitions.

An this is a specific case of JBPM clustered environment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

jBPM doesn't have any custom implementation of the Partitioner, so it's using the default one:

> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner

You can dive into the details there, but basically, it calculates a hash from the key for deciding which partition is assigned.

In the Kafka Emitter and  Kafka Extension (not in the Kafka Workitem), this property can be defined to overwrite the partitioner class, using the corresponding jbpm kafka prefix:

emitter:

> org.kie.jbpm.event.emitters.kafka.partitioner.class

extension:

> org.kie.server.jbpm-kafka.ext.partitioner.class